# HVAC Drain Pipe Broken inside Wall

Tags: hvac

Can I get to the drain pipe through the drywall inside the house?

When attempting to dissemble my exterior drain pipe (lower main pipe), I broke something inside the wall and subsequently there is water leaking inside of the wall.  Can I get to the pipe and fix it though the interior dry wall or do I have to cut open the wall from the outside?

Thanks,

Anacrusis

Comment: Need more info.  Are you 100% sure of the pipe's location all the way?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, interior drywall is easier to repair than exterior wall treatments. You haven't stated what your wall is made of, in my area the norm is stucco over lath and paper; much more difficult to repair properly.

I recommend an initial exploratory opening of the interior wall to assess damage and prospects for access and repair that way.

Comment: Just to be cautious: make sure there's no other plumbing or any electrical lines where you're about to cut.    You might also add:  cut a small hole and run one of those snooper-cameras into the wall to locate the break. You'd hate to take out a chunk of drywall on the first floor if the break is on the second floor!